# Raspberry Pi 4 stuck in serial.Serial()

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi4

I'm try to use RS232HAT With raspberry Pi 4 and I found this problem.

This is My code.

```
import serial
#print(serial.__file__)

dev = "/dev/ttySC0"
Baudrate = 115200

ser = serial.Serial(dev, Baudrate) <<< Stuck in this Function
print("START")
try:
    while(1):
        data = ser.read(value)
        print(data.decode("utf-8"))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("EXIT")
    exit()
```

When I interrupt by keyboard. The Program show this log.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "/home/pi/Desktop/2-CH-RS232-HAT/python/examples/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    ser = config.config(dev = "/dev/ttySC0")

File "/home/pi/Desktop/2-CH-RS232-HAT/python/lib/waveshare_2_CH_RS232_HAT/config.py", line 12, in __init__
    ser.serial = serial.Serial(ser.dev, Baudrate)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 240, in __init__
    self.open()

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 265, in open
    self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)

KeyboardInterrupt
```

My available devices:

[image: 1]

Comment: Welcome! Please consider that if you intend to use the SO, you'll greatly benefit from this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, please provide the error message you're getting in text form.

Comment: is that a "Serial HAT", "2-ch RS232 HAT" or "Serial Expansion HAT"... it seems they are all [possibly] slightly different and different kernel module arguments are required at boot time.

Answer (score 0):

you have to link the file, as example.
ln -s /dev/ttySC0 /dev/ttyS80
it sometimes cant read real serial info